# return "highlight" from userform to worksheet with vba in excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet and a userform shown in vbModeless mode, as I need it to be visible all the time. The userform includes a button. This button does a specific job, depending on the current selected cell at the worksheet. After pressing the button, highlight stays at the userform.

What I need is, after pressing the button, highlight to return at the worksheet and be able to scroll at the worksheet or use the arrows (keyboard), without having to clic at the worksheet first.
I tried this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ...
    Worksheets(1).Activate
End Sub
```

but it doesn't do what I want. I also tried the recorder but I got an error. What's the code for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
AppActivate Application.Caption
```